# Use file_get_html and extract content from the first span in a div

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

The html content is:

```
<div id="sns-availability" class="a-section a-spacing-none">
    <div class="a-section a-spacing-mini">
        <span class="a-size-medium a-color-success">
          In Stock.
        </span>
        <span class="a-size-base">
          Ships Soon.
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and from my code below, the output is :

In Stock. Ships soon.

I'm wondering how to extract only :

In Stock.

Can someone help?

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = "xxx";
$html = file_get_html($url);
$output = $html->find('div[id=sns-availability]');
$output = $output[0]->first_child();
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would simply be:

```
$html->find('#sns-availability span', 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can probably add another firstchild()

```
$output = $output[0]->first_child()->first_child();
```

You only navigate to the div that groups the two sub-divs whos content is echoed. You need to get to the first one of those two children. As illustrated in my simplification here:

```
<div>
    <div> <-- you are here
        <span>In stock</span> <-- need to get here
        <span>Ships soon</span>
    </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According [documentation](https://www.asaltandbattery.com/lib/php/htmldomparser/manual/manual.htm)

```
// Find all <span> with class=gb1
$result = $dom->find('span.gb1');
```

try to

```
$result = $dom->find('span.a-size-medium a-color-success');
echo $result->plaintext;
```

Comment: while technically correct, one could gess that the html document is larger than the section we see, so using an ID instead of a non unique class (medium sized text) would ensure the correct element is selected